# Read assets xml file in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to add library for gradle dynamically from xml assets file. The gradle file should read  tag in each xml then compile them. I have try to research but cannot find the solution.

The format of xml file look like this: http://prntscr.com/gv0ex4

Are there anyone can give me a direction for this?

Thanks.

Comment: As you can see in the image, gradle will read the path from 'library' tag then compile it.

Comment: ok and whats the reason in adding that dependency in *asset file*? assets are for your app, not for a build system after all...

Comment: I have been building an mechanism which include core and plugins. I use xml file to enable plugin and the attached library